# Paypal Adaptive Payment for Personal Account to API to Personal Account

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is is possible to integrate Paypal Adaptive payment for this type of structure, Like a Group Leader will received money from all member using his/her Personal Account or Business account is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this specifically, but I'm pretty sure the application owner account would need to be a business account.  That app could then be used by personal account holders to send money to each other, though.